# Java jsoup link ignore

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I have the following code:

```
private static final Pattern FILE_FILTER = Pattern.compile(
        ".*(\\.(css|js|bmp|gif|jpe?g|png|tiff?|mid|mp2|mp3|mp4|wav|avi|mov|mpeg|ram|m4v|pdf" +
                "|rm|smil|wmv|swf|wma|zip|rar|gz))$");

private boolean isRelevant(String url) {
    if (url.length() < 1)  // Remove empty urls
        return false;
    else if (FILE_FILTER.matcher(url).matches()) {
        return false;
    }
    else
        return TLSpecific.isRelevant(url);
}
```

I am using this part when i am parsing a web site to check whether it contains links that contains some of the patterns declared, but I dont know is there a way to do it directly through jsoup and optimize the code. For example given a web page how I can ignore all of them with jsoup?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Does your code work as expected? If so why do you want to change it? Do you want to know how the work can be done more efficient?

Comment: Yes, the code is working, and I want to find a way to make it more efficient, thats why I thought maybe there is a way to do it with jsoup but I am not sure

Comment: I assume that your reg ex approach is an efficient way to do the job. Using jsoup will add memory and cpu consumption. If you do not plan to add other checks or want to learn how to use jsoup, I would not change the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *how I can ignore all of them with jsoup?*

Let's say we want any element not having jpg or jpeg extension in their `href`or `src` attribute.

```
String filteredLinksCssQuery = "[href]:not([href~=(?i)\\.jpe?g$]), " + //
                               "[src]:not([src~=(?i)\\.jpe?g$])";

String html = "<a href='foo.jpg'>foo</a>" + //
              "<a href='bar.svg'>bar</a>" + //
              "<script src='baz.js'></script>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

for(Element e: doc.select(filteredLinksCssQuery)) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

#### OUTPUT

```
<a href="bar.svg">bar</a>
<script src="baz.js"></script>
```

---

```
[href]                      /* Select any element having an href attribute... */
:not([href~=(?i)\.jpe?g$])  /* ... but exclude those matching the regex (?i)\.jpe?g$ */
,                           /* OR */
[src]                       /* Select any element having a src attribute... */
:not([src~=(?i)\.jpe?g$])   /* ... but exclude those matching the regex (?i)\.jpe?g$ */
```

You can add more extensions to filter. You may want to write some code for generating `filteredLinksCssQuery` automatically because this CSS query can quickly become unmaintainable.